# Weird javascript behaviour with for()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have a function like this:

```
var dostuff = function(thing){
  var count = myvar.length; // <- I know for sure it's larger than 1
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    whatever(myvar[myvar.length - 1]);
},
...
dostuff(thing);
...
```

The problem is that the for loop only executes `whatever()` once, even if the count variable is 4, 10, 20, 100...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It should work the way you have, we need to see more code to give a proper answer

Comment: well, this seems ok, can we see the rest of the code?

Comment: but could the whatever function influence the for counter?

Comment: @Alexandra: no, count should have *saved* the value of `myvar.length` so even if it changes in the loop it shouldn't change anything. It is possible that there's an error in you code after the first time around and the code is failing, try opening up the console and see if you get any errors

Comment: ok, I found the issue. It's because I'm using the `i` variable in the whatever function. If I change `i` with a different name it works... But that's still weird, because `i` is defined in each function...

Comment: i is *not* declared in the code you posted, it is initialised without being declared so it becomes global. If you've done the same in whatever() then they are clobbering each other. You can only declare a variable using var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does whatever() also have a loop with the "i" variable?  it might be setting i globally.  you should declare i to be local to the dostuff function, and use braces for good hygiene:

```
for(var i= 0; i < count; i++) {  
    whatever(...);
}
```

Comment: that was it, but I didn't declare `i` outside these functions... I don't understand why each function is changing other function's `i`

Comment: whenever you ask javascript to get/set a variable, and JS doesn't find it locally, it assumes you mean it's a global.

Comment: obviously, using the "var" keyword is important when declaring variables that you mean to be local.

Comment: @Jeff Meatball Yang: attempting to "get" an undeclared, uninitialised variable will result in a reference error: '<identifier> is undefined'. Undeclared variables are made properties of the global object *only* when assigned a value.

Comment: javascript is great! It just takes a while to learn. I had this exact issue a while back because I thought the var was optional. I ended up just using `ii` as my loop counter :P If you want to avoid problems like this, http://www.jslint.com/ is a great site for making sure your code is really really really strictly formed.

Comment: Read [a couple](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) [of articles](http://zef.me/2843/javascript-the-scope-pitfall) about JavaScript scopes.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks for the technical insight, but A) you're not really rebutting my point that JS still thinks the code refers to a global, and B) the consequences of having unknowingly "set" a global are far more pernicious and less intuitive than the consequences (errors) of trying to "get" an undeclared variable.

Comment: jslint says: `Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.` :x

Comment: like david said, jslint is really strict. I prefer to declare them as I use them, TYVM. :)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but, if you want to call your `whatever` function for each item in `myvar`, you should use this :

```
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    whatever(myvar[ i ], thing);
```

Note the `i` instead of `myvar.length - 1`

Comment: if you're going in that direction, mightn't you just use the `for(i in myvar...` syntax?

Comment: @Shad: Not if you only want the numbered properites and not all of them

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to **alert()** the value of myvar.length? also is myvar a global variable? Pascal is right you probably want to be using i as its value will count through your myvar object unless the whatever function changes the length of myvar?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong, but what i'd start with:

- Couple of tweaks, just to be sure:

> ```
> for (**var** i = 0; i < count; i++) **{**
>   whatever(...);
> **}**
> ```

- What Pascal said :-D

Man i guess i'm a slow typer!